# Iterating Through Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

```
for (i = 1; i < total.length; i++) {
    $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") ul.qItem li :input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        total[i] += parseInt($(this).val());
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report div.scorebox").html(total[i] + " / 15");
    });
    if (total[i] > 11) {
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.t12").toggle();
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report div.scorebox").css("color", "green");
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report span.opinion").html(high).css("color", "green");
    } else if (total[i] < 7) {
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.t6").toggle();
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report div.scorebox").css("color", "#900");
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report span.opinion").html(low).css("color", "#900");
    } else {
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.t711").toggle();
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report div.scorebox").css("color", "orange");
        $("div.category:nth-of-type(" + i + ") div.report span.opinion").html(medium).css("color", "orange");
    }
}
```

This for loop should iterate through 5 divs and sum the values of the input radio buttons selected in each of them. Then it should output the score in each of the 5 categories in a scorebox. Depending on 3 ranges, it should then output a different opinion on their performance (low, medium, high), color the text red, orange, or green, and toggle the visibility of some text offering advice (t6, t711, t12). Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be able to put the score in the scorebox or select the correct text to show. Can anyone suggest how to have this script operate on each div in turn?

Comment: Your code looks fine, as long as these two assumptions are correct: 1) you have the plugin or extended jQuery to support nth-of-type selector, and 2) the structure of your HTML is a bunch of 'category' divs, and inside each of those divs are all the 'advice' divs and a 'report' div; and inside the 'report' div is the 'scorebox' and 'opinion'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has this built in.

```
$('selector').each(function(index, element) {

});
```

[$(selector).each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Useful for the OP to know, but it doesn't actually help with the question. `for` loop is a valid and sometimes desirable iterator and will perform far better than `.each()`

Comment: "Can anyone suggest how to have this script operate on each div in turn?"
The OP did not mention performance. That is irrelevant.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I use `.each()`, too. I simply meant that it's unclear if there is a `selector` he can use that will cause 5 iterations. ;-) His index is based on length of an array of numbers, which may or may not correlate to an array of `selector` objects. Either way, it's not the `for` loop itself that is the problem. Despite the wording of the final phrase, it seems that the problem isn't "how do I iterate?" (the `for` loops is just fine) but rather "why is scorebox not populated and text updated in 5 passes?"